# How do I calibrate my tablet's pen?

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I've got a Lenovo X230 Tablet that suddenly lost the ability to track the pen.  It acts like the pen is always in the upper left corner of the screen.  The touch screen portion also failed at the same time, but was restored by a reboot.  Unfortunately, rebooting has not helped the pen interface.  All Lenovo drivers are current.  I've been unable to locate any recalibration utility amongst the Lenovo software.

Comment: I don't have one handy to check...but there certainly a calibration utility, I've used it.  Check the device properties for the digitizer maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple new Lenovo updates came out today.  Despite neither one appearing to be related to the digitizer at all (Access Connections for example), the pen digitizer magically started working again after installing them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps, but this names the utilities used to calibrate on this exact model:

http://www.jessebandersen.com/2012/06/lenovo-thinkpad-x230-tablet-touch-and.html

Comment: Helpful as it showed me where to find the calibration utility.  Unfortunately it refuses to calibrate.  I press and press on the crosshairs and nothing happens.  Eventually the calibration utility quits and I'm left exactly where I started.  :-(

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Does the pen have batteries? I'm guessing that either the pen is dead or faulty, or the drivers are missing for the digitizer.

Comment: Here are the drivers for digitizer if you need them:
http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS014979